# jquery: get value and id of textbox when it changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a Jquery noob, very much in the learning stage.
  This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4tjof34d/

(Double click any of the three dots to get a textbox in the above fiddle, then enter a value in that box and press enter)
As you can see it works but how do I get the id and value when the user puts a new value into the textbox?

Basically, I need to get the value in to something like this:

```
var theId  = $(this)id;
var newValue = $(this)value;

// console.log(theId+" "+newValue+ " "+savedData);
```

so I can make an AJAX call to update the DB with the new value/s.
If you could put a comment in the code as well, for example:

```
// ajax call here
```

that would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you're using jQuery, but it's actually easier to get the values without it:

```
var showText = function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

However, to get the values with jQuery, simply use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var showText = function() {
  // Cache $(this) since we're
  // using it more than once.
  var $this = $(this)

  console.log($this.attr('id'))
  console.log($this.val())
}
```

Comment: If I put it in showText() wont that be called on every alphabet the user enters?

Comment: I didn't dig too deep into your code, but `showText` is where you're updating the values, right? So you would AJAX there. Also, you'll want to check if the input is still focussed in the `keypress` callback, currently it's possible to fire `showText` twice.

Comment: Thanks!, Its working in showText(). I am not sure how to do this part: `you'll want to check if the input is still focussed in the keypress callback, currently you can fire showText twice`

Comment: You're listening to both `keypress` and `blur` events on the input, when hitting return (`13`), it will call `showText`, then at the same time, it will blur the input, calling the `blur` event, which will call `showText` again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain JavaScript as follows:

```
var theId = this.id; //or $(this).attr('id');
```

and

```
var newValue = this.value; //or $(this).val();
```

**THE HOW & WHERE**

```
var showText = function () {
    $(this).hide();//show text
    $(this.nextElementSibling).show();//hide input
    $.ajax({
        url: '....',
        data: {id: this.id, value: this.value},
        ....
    });
};
```

Comment: Where do you need the `id` and `value`?

Comment: I need it as onblur() of the textbox... (when the person clicks out of the textbox or presses enter) Daryl's solution is kind of working for me, but will vote your answer up

Comment: I have included where to place the values and the ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

With Jquery for any input element you can use .val() function . So your syntax will be like

```
$("selector").val();
```

Now the syntax for this selector will keep on varying. For ex - if you want to get value for any specific id for an input element you use "#". So if you have an input field with an id of "testId" you will be doing

```
<input type="text" id="testId" class ="testClass"/>
$("#testId").val();
```

In place of id if you want the same value but with the help of class attribute you will be doing

```
$(".testClass").val();
```

Now if you have some other fields other than input fields you should ideally be using .text() for them.

So if you have a div with an id of testDiv you just need to do

```
<div id ="testDiv" class="testDivClass">Test</div>
$("#testDiv").text();
$(".testDivClass").text();
```

Just an advice, since you are learning jQuery right now refrain yourself from using hybrid things (mixing core javascript) just for the sake of finishing all the work. This way you may have to spend some time in learning things but ultimately you will be learning things in much better way

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning

Answer (score 1):

use `.attr()` and `.val()` to get attribute and value:

```
 $(this).attr('id');
```

and

```
 $(this).val();
```

Comment: I'm a JQ noob, can you tell me _where_ I put that above code please?

Comment: @Ryan: in the keypress event of textboxes.